# C++ - String Array Parameter for SetUnion function

Tags: c++, arrays, string, compiler-errors, set-union

I wrote a function to compute the union of two sets.

I'm running into several compilation errors and I believe that's in part due to how I made the `StringUnion` array and declared it but nothing I do is working thus far.

This is my header file.

```
#ifndef StringSet_header
#define StringSet_header
#include <memory>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::unique_ptr;
using std::make_unique;

class StringSet{
public:
    //create an empty set
    StringSet() = default;
    StringSet(int capacity);

    //copy a set
    StringSet(const StringSet &);

    StringSet& operator[](const int);

    //Insert a string to the set
    bool insert(string);

    //Remove a string from the set
    bool remove(string);

    //Test whether a string is in the set
    int find(string) const;

    //Get the size of the set
    int size() const;

    //get string at position i
    string get(int i) const;

    //Return the set union of the set and another StringSet
    StringSet setunion(const StringSet&) const;

    //Return the intersection of the set and another StringSet
    StringSet intersection(const StringSet&) const;

    //Return the set diffference of the set and another StringSet
    StringSet difference(const StringSet&) const;

    //prevent default copy assignment
    StringSet& operator=(const StringSet&) = delete;

    int NOT_FOUND = -1;
    static constexpr int def_capacity {4};
private:
    int arrSize {def_capacity};
    int currentSize {0};
    unique_ptr<string[]> arr {make_unique<string[]>(def_capacity)};

};

#endif
```

And this is my implementation of my `SetUnion` function.

```
StringSet StringSet::setunion(const StringSet &Array2) const
{
    StringSet StringUnion = make_unique<string[]>(arrSize);

    if (currentSize > 0)
    {
        for (auto i=0; i < currentSize; i++)
        {
            auto s = arr[i];
            StringUnion.insert(s);
        }
        for (auto i=0; i < Array2.currentSize; i++)
        {
            auto s = Array2[i];
            if (StringUnion.find(s) == NOT_FOUND)
            {
                StringUnion.insert(s);
            }
        }
    }
    else    
    {
        auto result = StringSet();
        return result;          //return empty StringSet}
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
|error: conversion from 'std::_MakeUniq<std::basic_string<char> []>::__array {aka std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char> []>}' to non-scalar type 'StringSet' requested|

error: passing 'const StringSet' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

error: no matching function for call to 'StringSet::find(StringSet&)'

error: no matching function for call to 'StringSet::insert(StringSet&)'
```

Insert and find work as intended to and I was able to use insert and find functions within my remove function and some others so why can't I use them here?

Comment: Initialize `StringUnion` as follows: `StringSet StringUnion(arrSize);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your line

```
StringSet StringUnion = make_unique<string[]>(arrSize);
```

The RHS uses the c++14 [construct that takes an `std::size_t`, and returns an `std::unique_ptr<std::string>` internally pointing to an array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).

The LHS, however, is a `StringSet` object.

You did not define a constructor taking such a type, so it's a problem.

Looking at your code, `StringSet` does have a `std::unique_ptr<std::string>` member, so you could add a ctor taking such an object, and initializing the member from it. However, it's unclear what would be the benefit of such a ctor, as you already have a ctor

```
StringSet(int capacity);
```

which already essentially does the same.

As Leon writes, you should just use this one instead of the line you have

```
StringSet StringUnion(arrSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

The errors provides by your compiler seem pretty clear. Let's check them.

- **conversion from `std::make_unique ...` to non-scalar type `StringSet` requested**

It's because of the definition of the function `std::make_unique`, which [returns](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) a `std::unique_ptr<T>`. But you're trying to assign it to a value of type `StringSet`. There is no constructor or operator for creating a `StringSet` from a `std::unique_ptr`, so the compiler complains that he can't do that.

- **error: no matching function for call to `'StringSet::find(StringSet&)'`**

Your class `StringSet` has an `operator[]` that returns a reference on a `StringSet` so `auto s = Array2[i];` is of type `StringSet`. But your functions `find` and `insert` ask for a `std::string`. As there is no constructor that can provide implicit conversion from `StringSet` to `std::string`, the compiler complains.

Comment: So by modifying my .h file's operator[] to return a string instead this should fix things? If it's a reference then just giving the string value back should be okay.